# See if username is taken or not, using ajax $.POST()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the block that checks if returned value = 1:

```
                } else if (validateUsername(username.val()) == 1) {
                    errors.html("That username already exists! Please use another.<span id='close'>X</span>");
                    errors.fadeIn("slow");  
                    username.css("border", "solid 2px red");                    
                }
```

If yes, username exists..

Now let's do the ajax work.

```
    function validateUsername(username) {
        $.post("js/ajax/ajax.php", { validateUsername : username }, function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

This will send a request to ajax, and fill var data with the response.

```
if (isset($_POST['validateUsername']))
{
    echo 1;
}
```

this is the ajax that will send a response, basically it's int 1 for now, for checking.

But, I always get undefined.
I mean, fireBug does say "request=1", but it looks like the if statement won't work.

If I just do return 1; manually without ajax, it will work.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: And I thought I knew everything about it!..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, so when you return data here :

```
function validateUsername(username) {
    $.post("js/ajax/ajax.php", { validateUsername : username }, function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

and try getting it here :

```
validateUsername(username.val()) == 1
```

it won't work, as the ajax call hasn't completed yet (and the return returns from the inner function only).
Instead you should do:

```
function validateUsername(username) {
    return $.post("js/ajax/ajax.php", { validateUsername : username });
} 

validateUsername(username.val()).done(function(data) {
    if ($.trim(data) === 1) {
        errors.html("That username already exists! Please use another.<span id='close'>X</span>");
        errors.fadeIn("slow");  
        username.css("border", "solid 2px red");       
    }
});
```

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded - just added one ?

Comment: So if I am correct, basically .done waits until it gets a response from validateUsername(), if yes.. data = the result sent by ajax?

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded - yes, the deferred is returned from the validate function, and done() waits until the ajax call is done, ***and then*** you can compare the values. Any sooner and there are no values to compare!

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded And just to be clear, by "done", it really means "successful". So the `done` callback will only run if the request is successful...you can also use `.fail(function ....)` to catch request errors.

Comment: @Ian - ^^^good point, it's a bit confusing with the name `done()`, the old `success` was a more descriptive name, but `always()` and `fail()` are good names.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah I like `always` and `fail`, but find it hard to justify `done` as the name for its real purpose. But I guess if we learn to accept these three names, we should easily know what each do :)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax functions are asynchronous. `validateUsername()` returns before the ajax call is complete (without a return value, which is why you see undefined).

Probably the most elegant way to handle this would be to refactor to `return $.ajax...` and work with the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX stands for ***Asynchronous*** JavaScript And XML. Ignore the XML part, but the Asynchronous is what's biting you in the backside here.

Anything that depends on the result of an ajax call must be in the success handler, called by the success handler, or defined in such a way that it will only be run after the success handler.